# How to Change the DPI of an image using the PIL without saving?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am trying to process numerous images through tesseract. Nonetheless, I have just discovered that by increasing the dpi I obtained better results. I have tried looking throughout StackOverflow on how I could possibly increase the dpi of an image, but all of the answers that I have found involved in changing the dpi while saving the file so something similar to this:

```
img.save('test.png', dpi=(300.0, 300.0))
```

Therefore I was wondering If it is possible to do this without necessarily saving the file.

I have trying doing the following:

```
image = Image.open('test.png', dpi=(300.0, 300.0))
```

but sadly it doesn't work

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: You can use BytesIO to "save" the file into a buffer, then reload the image by opening it with the buffer. `from PIL import Image; from io import BytesIO as bio; b = bio(); img = Image.open("my_img.png"); img.save(b, dpi=(300.0, 300.0)); img = Image.open(b);`

Answer (score 5):

The PNG format stores DPI information in a metadata chunk in the file, it's called a "pHYs" chunk. So, you're really looking for a tool which can edit or add these kinds of chunks in/to PNG files without reading the image data itself.

A library which can do that is [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng.html) and there exist [Python bindings](https://pypi.org/project/pypng/) for it.

You might also want to check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1551532/setting-dpi-for-png-files) which addresses the same problem. Apparently there are tools like [IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) and [ImageMagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) which can change PNG files, like putting a pHYs metadata block in it.

Comment: Hey thanks for you answer, actually I figured out that `image = image.resize((1080, 1080))` does the trick

Comment: That is not changing the density, but changing the physical number of pixels in the image by resizing. So your question was misleading

Answer (score 0):

Just posted an answer here: [How to change the dpi or density when saving images using PIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54001029/how-to-change-the-dpi-or-density-when-saving-images-using-pil/60065420#60065420), and I found this as well. I think the full answer posted on this will answer your question. In brief I would suggest to save a temp file and then delete it after you are done with it. I couldn't find any other workaround.