# How to change the dpi or density when saving images using PIL

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to compress a jpg file using PIL (to be more specific, Pillow)

I know images can be compressed by doing this:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open(img_path)
im = im.resize(new_size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
im.save(output_path, optimize=True, quality=50)
```

But I want to go further by tweaking more params, like this:

```
im.save(output_path, optimize=True, quality=50, jfif_unit=1, dpi=(72,72), jfif_density=(72,72))
```

Unfortunately, it does not change dpi or density at all. How am I suppose to achieve that?

Comment: Related: [How do I properly set DPI when saving a pillow image?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31351384/190597). The dpi setting only affects metadata. The actual dpi is dependent the resolution of the output device.

Comment: Thanks! I did not aware of that before.

Comment: Just so you don't fall into this trap, when trying to set DPI using Pillow, use a newer version if possible. I was having problems with 6.0.0 not saving DPI correctly. I'm using 8.2.0 and it is definitely working. Sort of unrelated to you actual question, but some folks might find it useful.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

With a little help from some articles here and there I came up with the below:

```
def set_image_dpi_resize(image):
    """
    Rescaling image to 300dpi while resizing
    :param image: An image
    :return: A rescaled image
    """
    length_x, width_y = image.size
    factor = min(1, float(1024.0 / length_x))
    size = int(factor * length_x), int(factor * width_y)
    image_resize = image.resize(size, Image.ANTIALIAS)
    temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='1.png')
    temp_filename = temp_file.name
    image_resize.save(temp_filename, dpi=(300, 300))
    return temp_filename
```

The above changes the dpi (to 300) and resizes the image. It saves all the results to a temporary image.

Though you may not want to change the size sometimes but only the dpi, therefore you can use the below:

```
def set_image_dpi(image):
    """
    Rescaling image to 300dpi without resizing
    :param image: An image
    :return: A rescaled image
    """
    image_resize = image
    temp_file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False, suffix='.png')
    temp_filename = temp_file.name
    image_resize.save(temp_filename, dpi=(300, 300))
    return temp_filename
```

For all the above you will need two imports:

```
from PIL import Image
import tempfile
```

I understand that if you run a code to check many images in batch (e.g. I am looping through thousands of photos, doing this operation for each one of them) you do not want your App Data temp folder to be full with temps. Therefore I also have a delete close method (to close the file) and a delete method (to delete it from my temp). Please note that you cannot delete it without closing it:

```
def close_image(image):
    """
    Closes opened image
    :param image: An image
    :return: None
    """
    image.close()


def removing_file(path):
    """
    Removing file by path
    :param path: The path of a file
    :return: None
    """
    # Try/except library import
    try:
        import os  # Miscellaneous OS library
    except ImportError as ImportException:
        raise ImportError("Cannot import needed libraries. Please contact administrator and give the code FN0001")
    os.remove(path)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Why do you have to use the Temporary File? Can't we simply save the old file?

Comment: Happens at times that you do not need to save the original file... When saving is out of your control at the time you are making changes to the file.

Comment: I'm using a screenshot image of 96 DPI, it seems that it is not working to increase my image DPI to 300.

Comment: Do you receive any errors or do you just realize that the DPI is not increased?

Comment: Using `image.save(path, dpi=(300, 300))` works for me. Note that if your image is exported without 'distortion' (without being pixelated) for a given dpi value, increasing the dpi will not affect the resulting image since it is already at its best resolution.

Comment: use BytesIO to save, temp files are a pain to use.

Comment: @yashas123 can you please give me an example? It is a pain to use indeed (not to mention the space if you have thousands of them)

Comment: @Svestis at the end this is what I did:
img = Image.open(fname)
img.save(fname, quality=95, dpi=(300, 300))

Comment: @yashas123 not ByteIO after all or I read something wrongly?

Comment: You don't need bytesIO either, when you open a file it creates a copy of it in `img`
If you insist on using it you can do
img = Image.open(fname) 
ib = io.BytesIO()
img.save(ib, quality=95, dpi=(300, 300))
return ib